# Change swift SKSprite node animation based on velocity

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Value of type 'SKSpriteNode' has no member 'velocity'

I want to change the animation based on the velocity of my SKSprite node, but I'm getting the error shown above and I'm not sure why

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

```
    if let location = touches.first?.location(in: self) {
    let horizontalAction = SKAction.move(to: location, duration: 1.0)
        horizontalAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeOut
      player?.run(horizontalAction)

        let playerAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "animation")
             var walkFrames: [SKTexture] = []
               var lwalkFrames: [SKTexture] = []


             let numImages = playerAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count
             for i in 1...numImages {
               let playerTextureName = "player\(i)"
               let playerLeftTextureName = "lplayer\(i)"
               walkFrames.append(playerAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(playerTextureName))
               lwalkFrames.append(playerAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(playerLeftTextureName))
             }
             walkingPlayer = walkFrames
             lwalkingPlayer = lwalkFrames

               let leftFrameTexture = lwalkingPlayer[0]
               let firstFrameTexture = walkingPlayer[0]

        player!.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

        player!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: firstFrameTexture,
                   size: player!.texture!.size())

        if player!.velocity.dx < 0 {
 //ERROR: Value of type 'SKSpriteNode' has no member 'velocity' ****
            player! = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftFrameTexture)
        }

        else if player!.velocity.dx > 0 {
//ERROR: Value of type 'SKSpriteNode' has no member 'velocity' ****
            player! = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrameTexture)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `player!.physicsBody.velocity`

(I know this isn't your question, but eventually try to not need the `!` everywhere -- use `if let` and `guard let`)

Comment: You answered my specific question so thank you! But now i'm getting another error which is "Referencing operator function '>' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'CGVector' conform to 'BinaryInteger'"  any chance you could help o.o

Comment: Yeah i'm really new to swift, I just started learning a week or so ago. I think I get the concept of if let, but its a lot more code and i'm not sure if I understand why its better

Comment: I don't want to just keep creating a bunch of new let variables right? Also some of my code necessitates an optional like where im adding a camera to the player sprite node.

Comment: Every time you use `!`, you are saying that you know for a fact that the variable is not nil. If you are wrong, your app will crash. Using guard let let's you check if it's nil, and if it is, then stop doing the rest of the function.

Comment: Vector does not support `>` -- what would it mean anyway?  You want to compare the magnitude of the vector probably (see `hypot()`)

Comment: Yeah I don't get what it means either >.< thanks for the help though! Appreciate you